# How to add tableau column header

Tags: tableau-api

I am trying to add rows to sheet to create a tableau table. I cant seem to think how to get table headers in the Y axis

It should look something like this.
[image]

However I have got something like this without the row wise headers or panes separating each row.
Also I want to look better

Heres what I got.:

[image]

Please help

Answer (score 0):

This is simple.. You have added all pills to columns.  Move measures to rows and let them be continuous only.  One tip for easy formatting like a cross tab.. double click second measure